# Regular expression validation fails while egrep validates just fine

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, grep

I'm trying to use regular expressions in order to validate strings so before I go any further let me explain first how the strings looks like: optional number of digits followed by an 'X' and an optional ('^' followed by one or more digits).

Here are some exmaples: "2X", "X", "23X^6" fit the pattern while strings like "X^", "4", "foobar", "4X^", "4X44" don't.

Now where was I: using 'egrep' and the "^[0-9]{0,}\X(\^[0-9]{1,})$" regex I can validate just fine those strings however when trying this in C++ using the C++11 regex library it fails.

Here's the code I'm using to validate those strings:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::regex r("^[0-9]{0,}\\X(\\^[0-9]{1,})$",
                 std::regex_constants::egrep);
    std::vector<std::string> challanges_ok {"2X", "X", "23X^66", "23X^6",
                                            "3123X", "2313131X^213213123"};
    std::vector<std::string> challanges_bad {"X^", "4", "asdsad", " X",
                                             "4X44", "4X^"};
    std::cout << "challanges_ok: ";
    for (auto &str : challanges_ok) {
        std::cout << std::regex_match(str, r) << " ";
    }

    std::cout << "\nchallanges_bad: ";
    for (auto &str : challanges_bad) {
        std::cout << std::regex_match(str, r) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or am I missing something? I'm compiling under GCC 4.7.

Comment: Why are you putting a backslash in front of the X?  From the shell that probably goes away so that the grep command just gets an X, but in code that might confuse something.

Comment: Are you using gcc by any chance ? Last time I tried, the regex library was not implemented and matches were failing silently. Try with boost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex fails to make the `'^'` followed by one or more digits optional; change it to:
`"^[0-9]*X(\\^[0-9]+)?$"`.

Also note that [this page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x) says that GCC's support of `<regex>` is only partial, so `std::regex` may not work at all for you ('partial' in this context apparently means 'broken'); have you tried [Boost.Xpressive](http://www.boost.org/libs/xpressive/) or [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/libs/regex/) as a sanity check?

Comment: Ah. I didn't know about partial support. I'll give boost a try. Thank you!

Comment: In this case "partial" means **does not work**.  Don't waste your time trying to use `std::regex` in GCC until someone contributes a working implementation.  As of GCC 4.7 it works for trivially simple REs such as `abc` but not anything with anchors such a `^abc$`

Answer (score 2):

> optional number of digits followed by an 'X' and an optional ('^' followed by one or more digits).

OK, the regular expression in your code doesn't match that description, for two reasons: you have an extra backslash on the X, and the '^digits' part is not optional.  The regex you want is this:

```
^[0-9]{0,}X(\^[0-9]{1,}){0,1}$
```

which means your grep command should look like this (note *single* quotes):

```
egrep '^[0-9]{0,}X(\^[0-9]{1,}){0,1}$'  filename
```

And the string you have to pass in your C++ code is this:

```
"^[0-9]{0,}X(\\^[0-9]{1,}){0,1}$"
```

If you then replace all the explicit quantifiers with their more traditional abbreviations, you get @ildjarn's answer: `{0,}` is `*`, `{1,}` is `+`, and `{0,1}` is `?`.